# Fail to get data from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working out with serial com port.
I have insert this code in my program.
I able to send data to the devices and fail to read data from the devices.
In debug mode, i only able to get serialport.BytesToRead = 0.
May i know why this will happen??

```
   while (serialport.BytesToRead > 0)
{
      int byte_count = serialport.BytesToRead;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[byte_count];
      int read_count = serialport.Read(buffer, 0, byte_count);
      string echo = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read_count);
      echo = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
      Console.WriteLine(echo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use another program, like Putty or HyperTerminal to verify that the device and connection is in working order and to double-check that you are using the correct port, baudrate, parity, stopbits and databits.  If you can't get anything out of the device with such a program then it won't work either using your own code.

Next focus on the handshaking.  A common mistake is to leave it at none and then not turn on the DtrEnable and RtsEnable signals.  A device won't send anything when it thinks that you're offline.  [SysInternals' PortMon utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) can be handy, it shows you what's going on at the device driver level.

Answer (score 1):

When to you read from the SerialPort? Are you trying to read right after you send? In that case you might try to read before there is actually anything to read from the port.

You should use the `DataReceived` event to read data.

Note that this event might trigger before all data is received, so you might have to retrieve the data over several calls of `DataReceived` until you get all the data you are supposed to.

Comment: If the event is triggering before all data is received, try setting the ReceivedBytesThreshold to a value equal to the expected packet size. This prevents the DataReceived event from firing to soon.